# How to add "read more" link to category pages

Tags: category, html

I want to create category pages that are similar to Houzz. See here: http://www.houzz.co.uk/photos/wall-lights

They have some introductory category text, followed by a more link that leads to more in-depth information positioned at the bottom of the page, after the products.

I'm aware that I would need to insert a block below my products for the more in-depth information, but how do I get my "more" link to work like Houzz? Is that possible to create within the Magento editor?

Thanks as always! You guys are great.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what js libraries you are using.  If you're using only prototype.js (default Magento) this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988088/jquery-scrolltop-equivalent-in-prototype

If you've loaded other libraries like jQuery you can add an id to the section at the bottom and use jQuery scrollTo plugin.
http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/